# Cloudflare Pages build fails: Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "/src/components/Snackbar"

Tags: reactjs, vite, cloudflare, cloudflare-pages

I'm trying to deploy my React app created with Vite to Cloudflare Pages. The build keeps failing with errors relating to my component paths like 'Failed to resolve ./components/Snackbar" and:

> Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import
> "/src/components/Snackbar" from
> "/opt/buildhome/repo/src/pages/Login.jsx". 19:05:32.362   This is most
> likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.

I've tried several different build parameters and relative paths with corresponding import statements and finally tried absolute paths by adding this to vite.config.js:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: "/src",
    },
  },
});
```

Unfortunately Cloudflare Pages keeps failing. On my local development machine, I can succesfully run **npm run build** / **preview**. Also, the same app works fine when I create it with create-react-app and push it to Cloudflare.

This has been bugging me for a looooong time.

Hoping anyone can help me solve this!

Thanks for your time,

Maarten